# Auto binding of bundles

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have my BundleConfig with many many bundles of css and JS.
Is there any plugins or tools to auto bind it?
For example I have HomeController and Content/Home.css or for example Content/Home/Index.css and this css files bind with view of my controller automatically.